# Deleting an object from an array is not completely deleting item

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsmutablearray, plist, nsmutabledictionary

Basically i have a list of check box on selection of which i am enabling them as checkmark on and creating a plist file

Structure :-

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<array>
    <dict>
        <key>Personal</key>
        <string>Pizza1</string>
    </dict>
    <dict>
        <key>Medium</key>
        <string>Pizza2</string>
    </dict>
    <dict>
        <key>Large</key>
        <string>Pizza3</string>
    </dict>
</array>
</plist>
```

and further selecting the same item i am undoing the checkmark and i am deleting the dictionary (using `removeObjectForKey`: ) from array and rewriting the plist file.

Structure :-

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<array>
    <dict/>
    <dict/>
    <dict/>
</array>
</plist>
```

So the problem is object is deleted from array but dictionary still exists ?

How to solve it ?

Comment: Why an array of 3 dictionaries rather than a single dictionary?

Comment: Use remove object at index will solve the problem

Answer (score 0):

```
removeObjectForKey
```

Is used to delete an entry form a dictionary. Array's don't have key's, they have indexes

```
removeObjectAtIndex:
```

Is used to delete an element from an array.

You have been emptying the dictionary of its contents, not deleting it.

Also on a side note, if this is your data structure, why do you need an array for dictionaries ? why not just one dictionary with multiple pairs ?

Answer (score 0):

Trojanfoe was right in asking why not just use a single dictionary like so...

```
@{
    @"Personal" : @"Pizza1",
    @"Medium" : @"Pizza2",
    @"Large" : @"Pizza3"
}
```

In your plist it will look like this...

```
<dict>
    <key1>Personal</key1>
    <string1>Pizza1</string1>
    <key2>Medium</key2>
    <string2>Pizza2</string2>
    <key3>Large</key3>
    <string3>Pizza3</string3>
</dict>
```

However, what you are doing at the moment is fine but you're not looking at it correctly.

You currently have an array with three dictionaries in it. Each dictionary has one key/value pari in it.

When you are doing `removeObjectForKey` you are getting one of these dictionaries and removing the key/value pair. The dictionary still exists.

If you want to remove the dictionary then you need to do something like...

```
[pizzaArray removeObjectAtIndex:theIndexOfThePizza];
```

This will remove the dictionary completely.

Answer (score 0):

When you use remove removeObjectForKey it remove object from the dictionary not the dictionary, for example if you want one dictionary with two object:

```
<dict>
    <key>Medium</key>
    <string>Pizza2</string>
    <key>Large</key>
   <string>Pizza3</string>
</dict>
```

and you call removeObjectForKey:@"Medium" the result will be:

```
<dict>
    <key>Large</key>
    <string>Pizza3</string>
</dict>
```

but if you call it when there is just one object like in example below you remove object from dictionary but the dictionary still will be there but empty.

You should get object from key and call:

```
removeObject:
```

or get index of the object and call:

```
removeObjectAtIndex
```